# Sharing image on facebook via Intent in eclipse

Tags: android, facebook

I am using the following code to share image to facebook but its not working.

```
                Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setType("image/png");
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                Uri.parse("/sdcard/img1.png"));
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(path);
sharingIntent.setType("image/png");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using"));
```

One, it should be in this order just for readability and sensical reasons

1. you need to say what the error is...
2. NEVER hardcode the path to the image '/sdcard/img1.png' use getExternalStorageDirectory() instead